# When did Perl 5 get Copy-On-Write strings?

Tags: string, copy-on-write, perl

I know the Perl 5 now has COW strings, but I can't remember when they were implemented.

Answer (score 5):

It appears to have been [Perl 5.20.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.20.0/perldelta.html#Performance-Enhancements):

> Perl has a new copy-on-write mechanism that avoids the need to copy the internal string buffer when assigning from one scalar to another. This makes copying large strings appear much faster. Modifying one of the two (or more) strings after an assignment will force a copy internally. This makes it unnecessary to pass strings by reference for efficiency.